# Angular 2 Large scale project with lot of modules

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have build a very large angular 2 cli application and it's working fine currently. But we are facing issues when we do releases to production environment.
5 teams are working on separate modules and some situations one or two modules must go live.
But when we build the project all the modules are being complied and all the changes are going live.

I tried to build each modules as separate angular2 libraries and host stable versions on git repository. We have one common project and all the modules has added to `package.json` as `dependencies` and teams are getting updates of other modules by using `npm install`.

In the common project routing as follows

```
export const routes: Routes = [

      { path: '', component: UsTileMenuComponent },
      { path: 'features/:id', component: UsTileFeaturesComponent },
      { path: 'users', loadChildren: 'app/modules/admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
      { path: 'sample', loadChildren: 'app/modules/sample/sample.module#SampleModule' },
      { path: 'shop', loadChildren: '@exce/sample#SampleModule' },
      { path: 'members', loadChildren: '@exce/membership#MembershipModule' },
      { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }

    ];
```

package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^4.2.2",
        "@angular/common": "^4.2.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.2",
        "@angular/core": "^4.2.2",
        "@angular/forms": "^4.2.2",
        "@angular/http": "^4.2.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.2",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^4.2.2",
        "@angular/router": "^4.2.2",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.26",
        "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "intl": "^1.2.5",
        "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
        "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
        "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
        "@exce/us-common":"file:///D:/WORK_DIR/HTML/modules/us-common/dist",
        "@exce/admin":"file:///D:/WORK_DIR/HTML/modules/admin/dist",
        "@exce/membership":"D:/WORK_DIR/HTML/modules/membership/dist",
 "@exce/sample":"D:/WORK_DIR/HTML/modules/sample/dist"
      },
```

In here I've get dependencies by using file Url insterd of git URL. In this approach Components, services, pipes inside libraries can consume but routing inside library did not work. It does not load as `{ path: 'members', loadChildren: '@exce/membership#MembershipModule' }`

Can anyone please suggest a solution for handling this ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to deploy some changes, and not deploy some other changes. That should be achieved by using a release branch in your VCS. Crate a release branch, merge the changes that must be released, then build and deploy that branch.

Comment: This can be achieved easily by source code management. You should have different repositories for development, test, qa, production environment, so that only the code in production repo will be built and deployed.

Comment: I edited my question. Thank you for the suggestion. It's the best way as I feel.